# Blank view list of tasks when using the message extension on Microsoft Teams android app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I had built an extension on Microsoft Teams and getting a blank view of a list on android devices i.e, the list is there but showing blank.

It's working fine in iOS and Android. please view the image below:

[image]

I tried multiple color in colorTheme option but it looks like it is not working. it is not reflecting anything on the extension.

```
response.data.data.forEach(obj => {
  const heroCard = CardFactory.o365ConnectorCard({
    title: obj.title,
    text: obj.percentComplete,
    summary: obj.Notes,
    "themeColor": "#6264A7",
    "sections": [{
      "title": `**Notes:** ${obj.Notes}`,
      "text": `**Created Date:** ${obj.createdTimestamp}`,
     }]
   });
   attachments.push({ ...heroCard });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I was using `o365ConnectorCard` and then I tried with `heroCard` it worked and now displaying on android devices as well.

Sample code:

```
response.data.data.forEach(obj => {
  const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard(obj.title);
  const preview = CardFactory.heroCard(obj.percentComplete);                    
  preview.content.tap = { type: 'invoke', value: { description: obj.Notes } };
  const attachment = { ...heroCard, preview };
  attachments.push(attachment);
});
```

[image]